# OS routine on an interrupt

Tags: operating-system, kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I'm reading on how a mode switch is performed in a process image and I'm confused on why a process image has a kernel stack and not just a user stack? This is done when an interrupt has a occurred. Doesn't the user stack and kernel stack do the same things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for security. A process usually has one stack for each processor mode. There is often either a system-wide or process interrupt stack that is an additional kernel mode stack.

The kernel stack is restricted to kernel mode access. This prevents user mode code from mucking with the kernel stack that would case bad things to happen in kernel mode (e.g., changing the return address from a procedure).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate the answer, but what if the user needs to change the return address can't it do it in the user mode?

Comment: User mode code cannot change the return address on the kernel stack.